# Why is my table not filtering? django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

So yeah, it isn´t filtering. I enter the search and the table doesn't filter. I have checked my code numerous times and it just ain't working. I need someone else's feedback because I'll go crazy. It probably is a very stupid mistake but you know how these things go. So, I've got my:

```
#filters.py
import django_filters

from .models import *

class ContratosFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Contratos
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'contractor', 'contractee']

#views.py
def contratostabla(request):
    contract=Contratos.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contract, 12)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    myFilter= ContratosFilter(request.GET, queryset=Contratos.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'contracts.html', {'contract':contract, 'myFilter':myFilter, 'page_obj':page_obj})

#contracts.html
                        <form method="get">
                            {{myFilter.form}}
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

My view also includes paginator and the table as you can see. The terminal says GET /contracts/?id=3&name=&contractor=&contractee=& . I would guess it is not posting it. I have no idea what is stopping it from working.

Answer (score 0):

you must add :

```
contract = myFilter.qs
```

after this line:

```
myFilter= ContratosFilter(request.GET, queryset=Contratos.objects.all())
```